# How do you validate an application's configuration?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2003

I want to run a system configuration check on an app machine where the check reviews required SQL connection, disk permissions, installed apps, and IP:port access (i.e. firewall isn't blocking outgoing access).  I'm using Windows Server machines and .NET framework if it makes a difference.

Is there a standard way of verifying an application can do all of these things?  For instance maybe there's an app where I can specify each of these requirements in a configuration file, run the app, and get back a status.

Thanks!
Ian

Answer (score 0):

Nop, there is no standard way, you have to add a console application in after installation steps while creating a deployment package that will do this checks step by step and show messages in console. I think this is the only way to embed custom steps in installation package using .net programming. Please let me know if you find any automation ;)